# Wordpress Hosting on microsoft Azure

Tags: wordpress, web-hosting, cloud-hosting

I have a wordpress CMS website (**www.example.com**-demo name) and  I have purchased domain name from Godaddy but instead of hosting my website on Godaddy or so, I want to host it to my server as I have taken some space over microsoft azure cloud.

But when I am doing this, it says (in domain name- *.azurewebsite.net) will be the complete url of website. So, how could I host it to microsoft cloud and the webiste URL will remain be **(www.example.com)**.

Replies are appreciated - Need help!!

Answer (score 0):

Glad to help. You can do this by connecting your domain name to your Azure account.  [There are detailed instructions on how to do that here.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-godaddy-custom-domain-name/)

Essentially you need to connect the CNAME record and IP address, and verify both to Azure and GoDaddy, which makes sure that you own both.

Comment: Glad to help. let me know if you need a hand. 

It may take a few minutes for DNS to resolve after you make some changes, too, so be patient.

Comment: I am blocked by asking questions from stackoverflow system because of low-quality questions, please upvote If you find questions OK.